# File naming for Enterprise GIS database?

Tags: python, grass-gis, file-formats

I'm designing the guidelines for an Enterprise GIS database.  Part of this database will include customized geoprocessing tools using a variety of software.

I'm interested in knowing whether anyone can foresee a problem with including '_' as a separator for filenames if GRASS GIS is being used as the main geo-processing software?

Most of the tools will be coded in python, SAGA GIS, and R stats will also likely be used as background processess.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although mostly tailored towards PostgreSQL, I've found few nice tricks regarding names in [PostgreSQL Database Conventions](http://blog.i2pi.com/?p=211). Perhaps that might offer some guidance. But you would definitely have to check them against GRASS, SAGA et al.

Answer (score 3):

For the record: I have been using '_' as a separator in GRASS within filenames for 15+ years and likely it will continue to work in the future, too :)